# OnClientClick OnClick

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my asp page, I take a screenshot of the client's desktop with an applet and ask them to send it to the server with a single click of a `LinkButton`. I use `runApplet()` function to call my applet to capture the screen and assign the strings value to a hidden value. (picture is stored as base64 string) Until here, everything works perfect! However, SendLinkButton_Click doesnt seem to be executing!

**This is my link button.**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="SendLinkButton" 
          OnClientClick="runApplet(); return false;"
          OnClick="SendLinkButton_Click" 
          Visible="false" 
          CssClass="portal-arrow portal-button"
          runat="server">Send</asp:LinkButton>
```

**This is my Javascript function**

```
   function runApplet() {

      var msg = document.capture.capture();
      var hiddenControl = '<%= inpHide.ClientID %>';
      document.getElementById(hiddenControl).value = msg;
   }
```

**and this is what's inside of SendLinkButton_Click**

```
protected void SendLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server.Transfer("Preview.aspx", true);
}
```

when I put the javascript function to a LinkButton's OnClientClick, and execute this "SendLinkButton_Click" with another LinkButton. It works perfect! But I want them to work with just one click!

Please help!

Comment: runApplet() :) just runApplet() sorry about the mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your client click is returning false so no postback will be made to the server after this point.

Try changing:

```
OnClientClick="runApplet(); return false;"
```

To

```
OnClientClick="runApplet();"
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `return false` from the OnClientClick attribute. If you return false from it, the postback will not execute.