# C# .NET OnClientClick returning true but OnClick not firing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have the following code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnHideDep" runat="server" Text="Remove this institution" CssClass="link1 small" OnClientClick="return confirm('Confirm remove?');" OnClick="btnHideDep_Click"/>
```

This button does not fire `btnHideDep_Click` when OK is pressed in the confirm box.
More interestingly, if i have `OnClientClick=return true;` the method `btnHideDep_Click` is still not fired. Also just to confirm, without the property `OnClientclick`, `btnHideDep_Click` is fired properly.

I read a few posts about this and it seems like this should work. So I must be missing something very basic here...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OnclientClick and OnClick is not working at the same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155048/onclientclick-and-onclick-is-not-working-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9484887/2096401) is relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Confirm remove?')) return false;"
```

Comment: The links above seem to do this: roughly, returning `true` says "I've handled it" so the `onClick` isn't invoked.